# How do I remove "object as camera" ? When trying to render, it's only capturing a close up section of one object in the scene Unsolved

Tags: rendering

Please help!! I'm going out of my mind

I'm only using one camera. I keep setting the camera to how I want and then when rendering its only showing a very small view of the room. I think it's because it was set to "object as camera"? but I don't know how to undo it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXkUr.jpg

first image is what I want to render - second is what is actually getting rendered

Comment: select a camera, then ctrl + numpad 0

Comment: @lemon Thank you for replying. Unfortunately that hasn't changed anything

Comment: could you share your file? please use https://blend-exchange.com/